# Can I hide typescript autogenerated .js and .map.js files in atom?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

Does anyone know if there is a plugin/option for hiding or grouping autogenerated files in Atom?

The files I want hidden/grouped is what the `typescript compiler` auto generates (`.js` and `.map.js` files).

Visual Studio style grouping would be best, if possible

My typescript file
`file.ts`

which generates
`file.js`
`file.map.js`

`file.js` is interesting to read once in a while, but in general its autogenerated and I shouldn't care about it.

So letting `file.ts` be a virtual folder like

```
- file.ts
  - file.js
  - file.map.js
```

would be the ideal solution.

Plain hiding is fine. (hiding `.js` files in general is not a solution, since typescript projects typically mix `.js`, `.ts` and even `.tsx` files)

Comment: There is this feature request : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/253

Comment: Until the feature is completed you can use the [tree-ignore](https://atom.io/packages/tree-ignore) package to hide the `*.map.js` files. This might be the best bad solution we currently have. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Atom respects `.gitignore` and will grey out any files matching your `.gitignore` which you place in the root of your project.  This should be sufficient to ignore generated files:

```
*.js
*.jsx
```

In addition, your `tsconfig.json` can output all your files into another path.  For example:

```
{
  "version": "1.6.2",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build"
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

This will inform `tsc` and `atom-typescript` to output all the TypeScript files located in `src` into `build`.

Comment: thx, I have upvoted, but I am not rep'ed enough yet - pitty :)

Comment: @MichaelBilling Even with your rep you should be able to "mark as answer".

Comment: @basarat your right, i'm just a SO noob! (btw. the question was also meant as a .-) to Atom plugin developers that the Visual Studio way of grouping files with same name is a fantistic feature. I'm not at all into coffeescript to make the extension myself. Though i did take a look at the tree-view code)

Comment: To add to this; if you have Atom open and modify the .gitignore file, you have to close Atom and reopen to see the effects of the change.

Comment: Did you mean to put [...] instead of {...} for the filesGlob object?

Answer (score 1):

Even better, the tree-view component in atom also has a setting to not show gitignored files at all:
[image]

It's the "Hide VCS Ignored Files" setting