# How to prevent webpack from generating .map files

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

Hei,

I'm setting up new Angular 2 project and I'm using webpack for bundling. I want to output files to separate folder (public). Problem is that webpack generates also .map and .js file for each .ts file. **I would like just one .map file in output folder or all .map and .js files in other folder than original files.** My code looks like this:

```
module.exports = (env) => {
 return webpackMerge(commonConfig(), {
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'public/js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'public/js/[id].chunk.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'public/js/[file].map'
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './public',
    port: 8100,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  },
 });
};
```

And base config:

```
module.exports = () => {
  return {
    entry: {
      'polyfills': APP_DIR + '/polyfills.ts',
      'vendor':  APP_DIR + '/vendor.ts',
      'app':  APP_DIR + '/main.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loaders: [{
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }
          } , 'angular2-template-loader']
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      allChunks: true,
      filename: 'public/styles/main.css'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'public/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

And output then becomes:

```
public
  js/bundle.js
  js/vendor.js
  js/polyfills.js
src
  one.component.ts
  one.component.js
  one.component.js.map
```

**NOTE:** not sure if webpack is responsible for this, I see .map and .js files getting generated on save although webpack is not even running. What could be the possible trigger?

Comment: I tried also that but it didn't help. But I found a problem, it was editor (plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was looking at the wrong place. It's atom editor (or more precisely it's typescript plugin) that is causing this behavior. But at least I figured it out and know where those files are coming from. Maybe it helps also to someone wondering about same thing and not thinking about editor being responsible for that.

Couple of links for hiding those files:

[Can I hide typescript autogenerated .js and .map.js files in atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691718/can-i-hide-typescript-autogenerated-js-and-map-js-files-in-atom)

https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/253

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your map file isn't from Webpack, but from TypeScript.  In your tsconfig.json try setting `"sourceMap": false,` if you don't want the map files at all.

Comment: I was looking at this setting and tried to set it to false but I still got .map and .js files. Finally I found the issue at atom-typescript plugin github repo that pointed me into the right direction. I started using visual studio instead. Problem solved. Or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the main section of your webpack config file, explicitly define `devtool` as `false`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  devtool: false,
  // ...
};
```